# Please help me prove nlogn -n belongs to Omega nlogn

Tags: algorithm

I try to solve this problem many times but I still don't have a solution.
The question as follows:

Use the definition of Big Omega to prove that

> nlogn - n belongs to Omega of nlogn.

Thank you

Comment: They kindly suggested that you use the definition of Big Omega. Do you know that definition?

Comment: The definition of BigOmega:
f(n) belongs to BigOmega(g(n))  when f(n) >= c.g(n) for any n > n0.

Comment: Perfect. Now what are f(n) and g(n) here?

Comment: Actually I said "perfect" but I'd like to rephrase that: f(n) belongs to BigOmega(g(n)) if there is an n0 and a c such that f(n) >= c g(n) for all n > n0.

Comment: f(n) = nlogn -n 
g(n) = nlogn

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As follows:

```
f(n) =  n log n - n
    >=  n log n - 0.5 n log n, for all n > 100 (assuming log10 base)
     =  0.5 * n log n,
     =    c * n log n,         for c = 0.5, n > n0 = 100
```

To summarize:

```
f(n) >= c * g(n),              for all n > n0 = 100, and
                               with c = 0.5, and
                               with g(n) = n log n.
```

Answer (score -1):

When logn > 2, then 1/2 nlogn - n > 0. Adding 1/2 nlogn to both sides gives nlogn - n > 1/2 nlogn.

This proves that nlogn - n is Omega(nlogn) (with the constant 1/2, and N the smallest integer such that logN>2).

Comment: How do you know start from logn >2

Comment: I figured out the condition for nlogn - n to be greater than 1/2 nlogn using basic algebra first, and then wrote down the proof using that solution as an assumption.

Comment: Thank you for helping me